# May I know why the tableview cell getting lazy while I'm scrolling?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, uiimage, sdwebimage

```
if (cell.tag == indexPath.row) {
    [cell.imageView sd_setImageWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:[enclosureUrlArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]]
                           placeholderImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"placeholder"] options:indexPath.row == 0 ? SDWebImageRefreshCached : 0];
                    CGSize itemSize = CGSizeMake(50, 50);
                    UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(itemSize);
                    CGRect imageRect = CGRectMake(0.0, 0.0, itemSize.width, itemSize.height);
                    [cell.imageView.layer setMasksToBounds:YES];
                    [cell.imageView.layer setCornerRadius:2.5f];
                    [cell.imageView.image drawInRect:imageRect];
                    cell.imageView.image = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
                    UIGraphicsEndImageContext();
                    cell.imageView.autoresizingMask = UIViewAutoresizingNone;
       }

    return cell;
```

I used SDWebImage only. While I'm scrolling my `UITableView` cells are stuck - it's not scrolling smoothly. I am retrieving images from a web service. Can you let me know why this is happening?

Comment: Please add a better description of your question / problem.

Comment: actualy while im scrolling its getting stuck tabelview cells its not smoothly.that is my problem. the above code i used. im getting images from webservice.

Comment: Where are the images located? It looks like you do to much work in the cell-method which is why it seems laggy.

Comment: just i mentioned image size thats it right

Comment: I think there is no need to set condition if (cell.tag == indexPath.row) try removing it. It is useless actually

Comment: ? But where are the images physically located?

Comment: @TMob he is getting images from server it is located there only

Comment: im fetching url from webservice n thn stored in enclosureUrlArray. and using default image view in tabelview cell.

Comment: Well you can't load the images when they should be displayed, the performance impact is way to high. You will have to load them (or some) at the loading of the view, preferrably asynchronously.

Answer (score 0):

In your code you will face a problem while scrolling the table view, because after downloading the image you're changing the image shape, like applying Bounds, Radius. So that image shape is changing every time. It'd be better not to use any 3rd party library but use apple APIs instead.

The code below might help:

```
cell.imageView.image = nil;
        dispatch_queue_t queue = dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_HIGH, 0ul);
        dispatch_async(queue, ^(void) {

            NSData *imageData = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL URLWithString:parsedData[@"imageLR"]];

            UIImage* image = [[UIImage alloc] initWithData:imageData];
            if (image) {
                 dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
                     if (cell.tag == indexPath.row) {
                         cell.imageView.image = image;
                    CGSize itemSize = CGSizeMake(50, 50);
                    UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(itemSize);
                    CGRect imageRect = CGRectMake(0.0, 0.0, itemSize.width, itemSize.height);
                    [cell.imageView.layer setMasksToBounds:YES];
                    [cell.imageView.layer setCornerRadius:2.5f];
                    [cell.imageView.image drawInRect:imageRect];
                    cell.imageView.image = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
                    UIGraphicsEndImageContext();
                    cell.imageView.autoresizingMask = UIViewAutoresizingNone;
                         [cell setNeedsLayout];
                     }
                 });
             }
        });
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want your table view to scroll buttery-smooth, I suggest you watch Session 211 of WWDC 2012, Building Concurrent User Interfaces and apply the concepts there. This features cells whose contents are independently queried and rendered.

The basic concept is as follows:
1. In tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath, a cell is instantiated.
2. In the same method, an operation for retrieving the data to populate the cell is created and stored into a dictionary. A reference to the cell is passed to the operation. The operation has a completion handler that populates the cell and removes the operation from the dictionary.
3. Before the cell is returned from the method, the operation is added to an operation queue.
4. In tableView:didEndDisplayingCell:forRowAtIndexPath, operations for cells that have moved off-screen are cancelled and removed from the dictionary.